# Error with html post form in internet explorer

Tags: php, html, forms, internet-explorer-8

I have a html form which posts to a php script. It works fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE. I have ran a test on W3C but can not find any errors that relate to the form. My code is:

```
<form class="formular" id="formular" method="post" action="script/contact.php"> 
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            <span>Name : </span>
            <input type="text" class="validate['required','length[3,-1]','nodigit'] text-input" name="Name" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Email address : </span>
            <input type="text" class="validate['required','email'] text-input" name="email" />
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" value="Contact" class="submit" />
    </div> 
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding ../ to your script/contact.php link, so it reads ../script/contact.php?

Comment: In what way exactly does it not work?

Comment: From those whacky class names, I'm guessing there's a client-side validator present. Have you checked for any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Form is correct. Looks like wrong handling form on server side. how you catch result?

Comment: I have tried, adding a / before the script but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Apart from a few Mixed spaces and tabs errors, the javascript file validates ok

Comment: When you say catch do you mean where I post it to?

Comment: can you try to extract only your form from whole template and run it in separate html file

Comment: I post it out to a php script - I will try and extract the form and let you know.